# Can't Remove Amazon ECS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have an Amazon ECS cluster, for some reasons I can not seem to delete it.

I've tried:

[image]

What should I look into before retry again?

Is there proper order I should follow ?

Is there a way to forcibly do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message shows that the container and cluster were built from a cloudformation template / stack. If so you should simply delete the stack itself from cloudformation.